# Why is it that "aggregate functions are not allowed in FROM clause of their own query level"?

Tags: postgresql

The former gives me the error message "aggregate functions are not allowed in FROM clause of their own query level" whereas the latter is permitted.  Unless I am much mistaken the latter is equivalent to the former because it just makes a new "local" name for `v`.

I'm writing a code generator so rewriting the former, natural form, to the latter, artificial form, is somewhat fiddly.

But what is the rationale for forbidding the former?

```sql
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT 0 as "v") as "T1"
 INNER JOIN LATERAL
 (SELECT
  SUM("v") as "r"
  FROM (SELECT 0) as "T1") as "T2"
 ON TRUE) as "T1"
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT 0 as "v") as "T1"
 INNER JOIN LATERAL
 (SELECT
  SUM("v_again") as "r"
  FROM (SELECT "v" as "v_again") as "T1") as "T2"
 ON TRUE) as "T1"
```

Comment: You need to ask the ANSI SQL committee members from the 80s when this was defined. Presumably, because they assumed it would be easier to implement for the database vendors (with the technologies available back then)

Comment: Thanks, where can I read about the relevant specification?  I'm also a little puzzled since I assumed that this issue can only occur with `LATERAL`, and `LATERAL` is not in standard SQL, is it?  I thought it was a Postgres-specific feature.

Comment: Yes, `LATERAL` is part of the standard.

Comment: LATERAL is standard SQL, it was introduced in SQL-99

Comment: FWIW, T491 LATERAL derived table

Comment: There are some freely available information regarding SQL-standard at https://www.wiscorp.com/SQLStandards.html

Comment: @TomEllis I run into the same thing, I searched for this but find no much, chatgpt explain but I do not get it well.... have you any insight on this?

Comment: I don't know why the restriction is there but rewriting the first form into the second form is fine as a workaround.